# Meteor Iron Router get Current Path from Route with Parameters in a Template Helper

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In a Template Helper I get the current path from [Iron.Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) (`iron:router`) as follows:

```
Router.current().route.path()
```

This works fine, unless the route path does contain parameters (e.g. `/client/:_id/edit`). In that case the `path()` function returns `null`.

How do I get the current path within a Template Helper, when the route contains parameters?

I'm using Meteor 1.0 with `iron:router`1.0.1

Comment: This sounds like a bug with Iron-Router itself. I would put something on their issues board on GitHub.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suppose the `_id` in your route comes from a collection, you need to pass `route.path` the document the route is based on.

```
Router.route("/client/:_id/edit",{
  name:"edit",
  data:function(){
    return MyCollection.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});

<template name="edit">
  {{myHelper}}
  {{pathFor route="edit"}}
</template>

Template.edit.helpers({
  myHelper:function(){
    return Router.current().route.path(this);
  }
});
```

I suggest you use the default `pathFor` helper for rendering an URL in the app.

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#pathfor

This helper is using the current data context (in this case `MyCollection.findOne(this.params._id)`) to extract route parameters.

But you can also use the path method from the route, which takes the document you want to generate the path for as first argument.

Comment: Perfect and detailed answer, thanks. I need the path in the context of navigation / highlighting certain items. I already had the setup exactly like you show it in the example, but did not know about the document (`this`) argument for the `path` function.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following alternative:

```
Iron.Location.get().path;
```

Works fine for me, when I need a path with parameters. Does not return the current route, though.

See [Meteor Iron Router does not get Current Path from Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741134/meteor-iron-router-does-not-get-current-path-from-route)