# Meteor Iron Router does not get Current Path from Route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In a Template Helper I get the current path from Iron.Router [(iron:router)](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) as follows:

```
Router.current().route.path(this);
```

**This works fine, unless the route path does contain parameters** `(e.g. /client/:_id/edit)`. In that case the path() function returns `null`.

How do I get the current path within a Template Helper, when the route contains parameters?

There are posts around covering the issue but the solution mentioned there seem not to fit.

I'm using Meteor 1.1.5 with iron:router1.0.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [iron-router/issues/289](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/289) there are problems when the path contains parameters. The suggestion to use `Iron.Location.get().path` This works well for me.

Comment: Worked for me, I'm using :slug parameter. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, I was able to use this to set classes to active based on the URL. Thank you!